Замена title и description для динамической страницы Брендов (Производителей)
Сайт разработан с помощью Opencart. Существует страница брендов (производителей), на которой генерируется плитка всех производителей продукции. В админ-панели есть вкладка Производители:

Каким образом можно поменять мета-данные (title и description) для подобной страницы? Или же необходимо подключение к сайту через FTP и менять в файлах?
Если в файлах, то подскажите по алгоритму, пожалуйста!

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
